# Deleting committed in files in local eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I was having trouble getting my eclipse set up for a new project, so I copied another project over and deleted the existing files.

However the commit history is saved for all of the old files. Where do I go to delete this commit history?

Using Eclipse Neon 3

Comment: That's what happens when you use git (or almost other source control system). What kind of system do you use? git?

Comment: yes I use git. Do you know if theres anyway to remove this? I'm sure eventually it will be buried underneath all my commits, but its going to annoy me for the minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the project, Team -> Disconnect. This will completely remove any revision information.

To create a repo with the contents of a fresh project, do the above, then close eclipse and via the command line in a terminal execute `git init` in that project's top folder. Open eclipse and the project is in a fresh repo without any history.